# How to Animate onkeypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to make my CSS animations run when the document detects a keypress. The goal for now was to make the div 'box1' slide out from the left. I managed to get it to work with onclick and buttons, but I want to it to slide out without buttons and on a keypress (with a button that has onkeypress, the button has to be selected first to work). Later I want to make a few animation events run on one keypress. You may have guessed, that I am trying to make a sort of "press any key to continue" page. Maybe there is a jquery plugin but I haven't found anything. Here's what I've tried so far, I only got up to creating an alert onkeypress for the document.

**HTML and Javascript**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Javascript Triggers</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function slideIn(el){
 var elem = document.getElementById(el);
 elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
 elem.style.left = "0px";

 }

 function slideOut(el){
 var elem = document.getElementById(el);
 elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
 elem.style.left = "-400px";

 }
 document.onkeydown=onkeydownhandler; 
 function onkeydownhandler() { 
 alert("Onkey down effect..."); 
 } 

 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <button onclick="slideIn('box1');">Slide In</button>
 <button onclick="slideOut('box1');">Slide Out</button>
 <div id="box1">Content in box1... </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
div#box1 {
background: #9DCEFF;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: -400px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than setting the transition css within your JS would be to set it on all relevant elements within your CSS, and then just set position - or better yet, a class or data- attribute - with your javascript.

Not necessarily an answer to your question, but I've always found it easier to find what's wrong if concerns are properly separated.

Comment: Alright, but there are a couple things I don't understand.. If I had say, two div boxes, and one was on the left, the other on the right. I want the one hidden on the left to come out to the right, and vice-versa for the one hidden on the right. How could I set a transition for both of them? But still.. I want to know a way of triggering an event with a keypress..